# Is it worth targeting below api11?

Tags: android

Search did not return anything relevat. As a developer I want to know what are the perspectives of releasing an app for android 2.x.x. I see that there are still many phones running it, but it looks like it is being discontinued so the number of phones should be decreasing, right? should I or should I not target it?

Comment: It will probably be around 50% of the total market for the next one or two years at least, it's decreasing pretty slowly. If you want to reach those users it's up to you.

Comment: are new devices being released on this platform?

Comment: In emerging markets like India, yes. But the devices being released are mostly feature phones which can just about run the OS. Your app will be severely limited in the amount of resources they have access to on these phones.

Comment: To add to what Vinay said, this is very true. I target lower API levels on my apps and I am seeing a lot of bad reviews from these phones because they are so limited in RAM and memory, and although it's the phone's fault my apps don't run great, they blame it on me. In retrospect, I would not support gingerbread and lower. It is a hassle, and not worth it when the phones running the gingerbread are mostly horrible new phones that have little RAM (I've seen 290 MB on some).

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, you made it very clear to me. I will not be targeting lower API levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recommends that you target the latest API Level always, because you as a developer can use the best available solutions.Now the distribution of devices is like  [image: this] according Data collected during a 14-day period ending on May 1, 2013.

You can see that its around 40% below api 11 and believe me it was around 50% a few weeks ago.. So its not recommended in the market sense also. See [Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

But if you are going to implement some special features which you need to work only in those versions then its fine.

Comment: yeah, definitely not then. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the type of question for this site but I believe I can give some relevant information. It really depends on the app you are building and the clients you want to reach. However, you can [See Here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) that a lot of users are still checking in to the Play Store with 2.x devices. So, in most cases, I would say that it would usually be beneficially to support those older versions while targeting newer ones.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer to this question.  You should first and foremost assess what your app should be doing and for whom...i.e. your target audience.  Gingerbread (2.3.3) as of May 1st is still the #1 platform and it seems it has been changing slowly.

I would say always target the newest APIs and use the support libraries whenever possible, meaning use the lowest level of support API that will still allow you to deliver all the functionality you need.  That way, you should always be developing for as wide an audience as possible.